# How reliable is adding an application manifest to ensure elevated privileges across windows xp, vista and 7?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, manifest, elevated-privileges

How stable is this method to ensure that my admin application requests admin privileges when launching:

`<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

</requestedPrivileges>`

This works well on Windows 7 but I do not have access to XP and Vista so cannot tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying that manifest, you tell Windows (Vista or 7), if a standard user (admin as well with UAC enabled) tries to execute this app, UAC prompt should appear. Without elevation, this app won't work as expected.

Both Windows Vista and Windows 7 can handle this properly, as that's why UAC is designed.

For Windows XP, a standard user needs to use runas manually to execute your app as admin, while an admin user can run it directly. There is no UAC on Windows XP, and it falls back to the old behaviors long time Windows developers familiar with.

To test out Windows XP, you should use Windows XP mode, http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

Comment: I had not thought of XP mode for some reason. Thanks for that suggestion. From your answer though, I gather that the admin can still pre-launch the app before the user gets to their machine. The app is actually supposed to run in the background and gather user interaction with an offline exam.

Comment: In your case, I strongly recommend you reconsider your app's architecture. You should be able to move admin-credentials-dependent part into a Windows service, while leave standard-user-friendly part in an app that can work for standard users. Then the app can talk to the service via inter-process communication. The design of UAC obviously enforces this kind of code cleaning-up, as developers tend to over-use admin credentials.

Comment: Thanks. I had initially developed a service but abandoned the idea because part of the core requirements were gathering information that a service is not allowed to do e.g. interact with the desktop. So the need for an annoying admin-only WinForms app was born.

Comment: A service in fact can interact with desktop in many ways. A typical show-case can be the anti-virus app you use. Usually its Windows service part initiates a standard user friendly app when you log on (which sits in system tray typically). Then any notifications from the service can be shown to you via this tray app, while any configuration you set within the tray app goes to the service. How to initiate the tray app in your session when you log on is the most difficult part :), but there are good approaches you can explore, too, which worth another question on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing by 'difficult' you are referring to event subscriptions for session changes, remote sessions, etc.?

Comment: Subscription to session change is easy for Windows services, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onsessionchange.aspx and Cassia provides other utilities, http://code.google.com/p/cassia/ But you still need to PInvoke CreateProcessAsUser to initiate the tray app in the logon user's session, which is not quite easy. Many articles/posts discussed about it, but not all of them cover all the details.

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP does not process the requestedPrivileges node, and does not have any kind of UAC mechanism.

UAC and the ability to set a requestedExecutionLevel were both introduced with Windows Vista.

---

Windows XP's standard accounts were strictly that, and there was no elevation mechanisim in place for administrative tasks to be performed short of logging in again.

Consequently the best practice for dealing with errors resulting from a lack of permissions on XP was just to display a meaningful error message.

Comment: What about standard and administrator accounts in XP. They DID have those. In other words are you saying that I do not need to (or cannot) implement anything to make my app XP friendly?

Comment: Under XP (and earlier versions of NT), standard user accounts are strictly that: Administrative level tasks had to be performed by logging in, separately, as an administrator.

Comment: Figures. I never used a standard account in XP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that manifest ensures that a user that belongs to the Administrators group gets properly elevated on Vista and up when they accept the UAC prompt.

What it does not do is give a user that *doesn't* belong to that group privileges.  Like the way it was done in XP but also in later releases.  A site admin may give users restricted accounts.  Which is okay, they are surely not supposed to run your program.  The admin didn't want them to.  Do check that you give a reasonable diagnostic.  WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) lets you check on .NET.

Comment: Yes I understand that and ensure that the process now does have enough privileges. What you seem to suggest about XP is a behavior unknown to me. The admin app actually records various user actions while they are giving an interactive exam. I'm guessing you would suggest that I, as the app dev, should recommend clients against using XP in the first place for such scenarios?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your answer, Lex's answer below suggests that the app CAN be run in admin mode WITHOUT giving the user admin privileges as well (which is what I want). Only that they or the aadmin would have to manually use the RUNAS launch condition. Your thoughts?

Comment: @RaheelKhan, you seems to misunderstand me. Did you ever use runas in the past? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294676 and http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true For a standard user on Windows XP, he/she must launch the app as an admin via runas. That requires admin credentials.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the comment on reasonable diagnostic.

Comment: @LexLi: I did not misunderstand your answer, just explained my understanding poorly :). Should have added the 'as long as they have the admin credentials' part.