# Running Windows Service in Foreground

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-xp

I have a bat file which is installed as a service. I can run the service on a remote box. This service needs to launch another application. The launched application needs to be visible(run in foreground). Currently the launched application is running in background as the windows service is running in background. How can i make the windows service or both the windows service and the application that it launches run in foreground? I intend to manage the service with the ServiceController class in C#.

Comment: It doesn't just run a little bit in the background, it runs in a completely different session with its own desktop.  One you cannot get to in Vista and up.  Google "session 0 isolation".

Comment: Session 0 isolation is for vista and up right? I'm in XP. is it possible in XP?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably read

http://asprosys.blogspot.com.au/2009/03/allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop.html

Making a service to just launch another app is a real security issue, what if your other app gets replaced with something else do you have all the checks in your Service to ensure your app is the app you think it is.

Comment: Security is not a major concern in my case. It is an internal server. I am not checking the "Allow service to interact with desktop" option. I am using impersonation instead. I know that there are security concerns associated with impersonation as well, but this is not production code. So back to the original question. How can i run my windows service in foreground? Is this possible?

Comment: In the article cited, there is information about how to do it. Including source to a project that shows the techniques.

Answer (score 0):

A proper approach is to launch the second application in the user's session, while your Windows service app always runs in session 0.

The approach has been part of my discussion with @RaheelKhan under this thread,

[How reliable is adding an application manifest to ensure elevated privileges across windows xp, vista and 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468010/how-reliable-is-adding-an-application-manifest-to-ensure-elevated-privileges-acr)

It requires proper understanding of Windows sessions, session isolation, and platform invoke.